# Cannot implicitly convert type void to System.Collections.GenericList

Tags: c#, list, void

I'm having a problem with lists.
In my for cycle I'm trying to add an element inside a list in a certain index.

The error I'm receiving for the list `FinalKnotsVector` is:

> "Cannot implicitly conver type 'void' to System.Collections.Generic.List"

Can somebody help me?

```
{

    [MultiReturn(new[] { "l", "n","FinalKnotsVector"})]
    public static Dictionary<string, object> InLength(List<double> Initialknots, int p, List<double> KnotInserted)
    {
        int l;                                      //OUTPUT: Length of the initial knot vector
        l = Initialknots.Count;

        int n;                                      //OUTPUT: Number of initial control points 
        n = l - 1 - p;

        List<double> FinalKnotsVector = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 1; i < KnotInserted.Count; i++)
        {
            FinalKnotsVector=Initialknots.Insert(i, KnotInserted[i]);
        }


        var d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        d.Add("l", l);
        d.Add("n", n);
        d.Add("FinalKnotsVector", FinalKnotsVector);
        return d;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: [`Initialknots.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.8) modifies the `Initialknots` list and does not return anything. So you cannot assign the return value to `FinalKnotsVector`.

Comment: `Initialknots.Insert` return type is void. You can not assign void to a List

Comment: You should explain what you want to do in `for` loop.

Comment: @poke hi and thank you. What I would like to do is to insert inside Initialknots some values taken from KnotInserted going through the for loop. How can I do? I want a new list not a void one

Comment: Copy the `Initialknots` list and then append to it: `FinalKnotsVector = new List<double>(Initialknots);` and then inside the loop: `FinalKnotsVector.Add(KnotInserted[i]);`

Comment: Hi @poke my goal is to insert two numbers {1,2} cointained in list KnotInserted inside list Initialknots which is a list made by {0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,4}. These numbers should be inserted after the same number found in list Initialknots. Therefore my result has to be {0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4}.

Comment: Hi @bahrom my goal is to insert two numbers {1,2} cointained in list KnotInserted inside list Initialknots which is a list made by {0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,4}. These numbers should be inserted after the same number found in list Initialknots. Therefore my result has to be the list FinalKnotsVector equal to {0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that like this:

```
List<double> FinalKnotsVector = new List<double>(Initialknots);
foreach (var value in KnotInserted)
{
    FinalKnotsVector.Insert(FinalKnotsVector.IndexOf(value), value);
}
```

This is simple straightforward way. See if this meets your requirements.

And pay attention that I am not changing `Initialknots` (*In your code however you are trying to insert an item into it*). If you need it to be changed as well then first change `Initialknots`, after that you can create your `FinalKnotsVector` passing `Initialknots` to the constructor like this:

```
foreach (var value in KnotInserted)
{
    Initialknots.Insert(Initialknots.IndexOf(value), value);
}
List<double> FinalKnotsVector = new List<double>(Initialknots);
```

Comment: Hi @bahrom sorry for bothering again but now I'm trying to find the index of a value in FinalKnotsVector and I'm stuck with the error "Argument 1:cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<double> to 'double'. I used to write : k = FinalKnotsVector.IndexOf(KnotInserted);